# mysql database event (like insert update delete) tracking for all table using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, real-time-data

I am new in node.js. I was just trying to build a module to track a record for all MySQL database activity with details using node.js.
as I want like someone insert/update/delete in MySQL db then data will show in our node console.
example- database my_work insert a row with value (......) when I hit a insert command in MySQL workbench.

Comment: Hi there - could you perhaps post some code to let us know what you have tried so far? To be clear, what you are looking for is an event listener for your MySQL instance that feeds up to your node server, rather than implementing database calls from node itself?

Comment: So far I installed one module in node named as mysql-events

Comment: var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');
var dsn = {
  host:     'localhost',
  user:     'my_work',
  password: 1234,
};
var mysqlEventWatcher = MySQLEvents(dsn);
var watcher =mysqlEventWatcher.add(
  'myDB.table.field.value',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {
     //row inserted 
    if (oldRow === null) {
    }
 
     //row deleted 
    if (newRow === null) {
    }
 
     //row updated 
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
      //update code goes here 
    }
  }, 
);